# ionic 1.3.1 with angularjs 1.5 components with ngComponentRouter

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i am working on a project named mobile messenger in which i am using angularjs 1.5 components as per requirement.
once i started working on this i was using ui-router for routing. but after using ui-router i found some issues in tabs e.g

tabs are broken
title is not visible
history issues
just to get rid of above issues i planned to use new angular 2 router ngcomponentRouter for angularjs 1.5 components. which is recommended by angular team.
but i am having lots of confusion in its use.i didn't find any suitable article for ionic 1.3.1 and angular 1.5 with new routing,
i am confused in how to use ngoutlet and other terms in angularjs 1.5. also i am scracthing my head just to find that

what exactly should i use with ionic?
should i use ionic 1.3.1 and angularjs 1.5 components?
should i use angular2 route i.e ngComponentRouter with angularjs 1.5 components?
if i use state routing after updating ionic version and angularjs version i found some issues mentioned above.

now i just want to know the right path to walk on. i am hanging in middle.

kindly suggest me on this.so that i can go ahead.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ionic 1.3.x` uses `Angular 1.5.x` but does not support the routing of components since it uses a old version of `ui-router`. You can find the reasons in this post on the ionic forum https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-1-3-release-candidate-w-angular-1-5-update/49133/8